# SPQuery ProcessBatchData from folders

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm using the following script to try and delete items from a Doc Library rather unsuccessfully. There are no files in the root, just all in subfolders under this doc library. Where am I going wrong on getting it to search the folders and remove from there?

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$urlSite = “”    
$listname = “Documents”    
write-host "Opening site..."    
$web=get-spweb $urlSite    
write-host "Opening list..."    
$list=$web.lists | ? { $_.title -eq $listName}    
$spQuery= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery    
$spQuery.ViewAttributes="Scope='RecursiveAll'";    
$spQuery.RowLimit = 200    
$caml = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>"    
$spQuery.Query=$caml    
do    
{    
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)    
    $count=$listItems.Count    
    $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition= $listItems.ListItemCollecitonPosition    
    $batch="<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-8`"?><Batch>"    
    $j=0    
    for($j=0;$j -lt $count; $j++)    
    {    
        $item=$listItems[$j]    
        $command="<Method>"    
        $command+="<SetList Scope='Request'>$($list.ID)</SetList>"    
        $command+="<SetVar Name='ID'>$($item.ID)</SetVar>"    
        $command+="<SetVar Name='owsfileref'>$($web.Url)/$($item.Url)</SetVar>"    
        $command+="<SetVar Name='Cmd'>Delete</SetVar>"    
        $command+="</Method>"    
        $batch+=$command    
        if($i -ge $count){break}
    }
    $batch+="</Batch>"
    write-host "Sending batch..."   
    $result=$web.ProcessBatchData($batch)   
    write-host "Emptying Recycle Bin..."    
    $web.RecycleBin.DeleteAll()
}
while($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
$web.Dispose()
write-host "Process finished"
```

I need to get 100,000 items odd items deleted and it seems like this is the only method but I can't quite get it working.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dmcinfo.com/Latest-Thinking/Blog/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/8471/Using-SPWebProcessBatchData-to-Update-Document-Library-Properties.aspx

Summary: When running ProcessBatchUpdate on a document library you need to pass the server relative url of the file in each item. Use SPListItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl or SPListItem.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl.

Change the following line...

```
$command+="<SetVar Name='owsfileref'>$($web.Url)/$($item.Url)</SetVar>"
```

to

```
$command+="<SetVar Name='owsfileref'>$item.File.ServerRelativeUrl</SetVar>"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to recurse the folder structure in the document library still.

Comment: Try use...$spQuery.ViewAttributes="Scope='Recursive'"

Comment: Same effect, doesn't recurse the folder structures.